# .htaccess language redirect: avoid infinite loop by detecting path segment

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to detect user's browser language and prepend path segment to base url. For example, one of redirects looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On    

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/de
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} !en [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} de [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /de [R=302,L]
```

I understand it like this:
If there is no /de segment after www.domain.com and requesting home page (www.domain.com) and English is not in prefered languages and German is in prefered languages redirect to www.domain.com/de.
My question is why `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/de` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/` are always **true**? Before inserting this redirect in my .htaccess i tested my config [here](http://htaccess.mwl.be/) (found in other .htaccess questions) and it worked. If you have another solution i welcome it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule should be refactored to this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/de [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} !en [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} de [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /de [R=302,L]
```

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/` will always be true because `REQUEST_URI` always starts with `/`. If you use `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$` then it will work as intended. Same thing we could do in `RewriteRule ^/?$` as well hence I removed that extra condition from my answer.

Comment: @enubhava yes, thank you. If i may ask one more thing: i used `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/` in order for this redirect to work only for www.domain.com page, so why it works as i intended without this condition ?

Comment: @enubhava sorry if my question was unclear, but i asked why your condition works only for www.domain.com requests (exactly what i needed) ?

Comment: It is because of this pattern `RewriteRule ^/?$` which matches only the landing page.